# Why do the MySQL bin log files still exist after a purge or flush?

Tags: mysql, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I've used PURGE BINARY LOGS as well as FLUSH LOGS, but the mysql directory still contains these files:

```
mysql-bin.000025
mysql-bin.000024
mysql-bin.000023
mysql-bin.000022
mysql-bin.000021
mysql-bin.000020
mysql-bin.000019
mysql-bin.index
```

Is there a reason why using the commands are not working? These files are taking a lot of space. I would like to get rid of them safely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`PURGE BINARY LOGS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/purge-binary-logs.html) statement deletes all the binary log files listed in the log index file prior to the specified log file name or timestamp. Deleted log files also are removed from the list recorded in the index file, so that the given log file becomes the first in the list.

I hope you have purged binary logs upto `mysql-bin.000019` using command

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000019';
```

If you need to purge all logs do like

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000025';
```

This will remove binary logs upto `mysql-bin.000025`.

**UPDATE**

You can try

```
RESET MASTER;
```

[`RESET MASTER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reset-master.html) Deletes all binary log files listed in the index file, resets the binary log index file to be empty, and creates a new binary log file

The effects of `RESET MASTER` differ from those of PURGE BINARY LOGS in 2 key ways:

1. `RESET MASTER` removes all binary log files that are listed in the index file, leaving only a single, empty binary log file with a numeric suffix of .000001, whereas the numbering is not reset by PURGE BINARY LOGS.
2. `RESET MASTER` was not intended to be used while any replication slaves are running. The behavior of `RESET MASTER` when used while slaves are running is undefined (and thus unsupported), whereas `PURGE BINARY LOGS` may be safely used while replication slaves are running.

## CAVEAT by RolandoMySQLDBA

If you run `RESET MASTER` with Slaves connected and running, the IO Thread of each Slave will immediately lose its place. Replication is thus broken and you will have to spend time getting the data on all Slaves sync'd again. If you want to safely delete binary logs from a Master without breaking Replication integrity, here is what you do:

- Run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` on each Slave.
- Take note of `Relay_Master_Log_File`. This is the binary log whose latest statement was successfully executed in the Slave).
- From all displays of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`, determine which `Relay_Master_Log_File` is the oldest (For example, 'mysql-bin.00123').
- You can run `PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.00123';` None of the Slaves will lose its place.

The overall effect? This will leave behind binary logs on the Master whose statements that have not been executed on all Slaves as of yet.

Comment: Yes. I've tried this. Not working.

Comment: PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000025'; When you run this what is the error.

Comment: Yes. I've tried this. Not working.

Comment: I have updated my answer.You can try RESET MASTER.

Comment: When I do that, it returns: "ERROR 1186 (HY000): Binlog closed, cannot RESET MASTER". What to do?

Comment: I hope You do not have binary log enabled.what is the result of show variables like 'log_bin'; ?

Comment: It was commented out :( . I see the problem now. Everything okay now. Thanks.

Comment: I added supplemental info on `RESET MASTER` with running Slaves. +1 for your answer nonetheless.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA did you mean the newest bin log in that third bullet point?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR No, I really meant the oldest. Let me clarify: If, at any time, you run `CHANGE MASTER TO`, it deletes all relay logs. If `Relay_Master_Log_file` is `mysql-bin.00123`, that's the oldest binary log on the Master that the Slave knows about. If `mysql-bin.00123` no longer exists on the Master, you could lose the proper place to replicate from if you run any `CHANGE MASTER TO` on the Slave that does not reference newer logs. This can easily be overlooked and you end up manually breaking replication.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Please read my posts http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/trying-to-understand-show-slave-status-g/18438#18438 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3905/mysql-replication-lag-behaving-erraticly/3907#3907 to understand why `Relay_Master_Log_File` is ALWAYS OLDER than `Master_Log_File` in a `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` output.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Fair enough. I misread what you were saying. That second linked post was pretty helpful in understanding slave replication though so thanks for that.

Answer (score 11):

In my case `PURGE BINARY` simply wasn't deleting anything.

I had my partition at 100% usage (I had to clean up my slowqueries log a bit so that there was enough space to mysql to be restarted), so the first thing I did was change `/etc/my.cnf` to comment the line `log-bin=mysql-bin` (it wasn't needed in this server anymore and I had forgotten to remove it), and then I restarted mysql (this was needed because there were queries queued that were preventing `PURGE BINARY` from being executed).

After that, I ran `PURGE BINARY` but nothing happened. So I read the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/purge-binary-logs.html) and found out that:

> This statement has no effect if the server was not started with the --log-bin option to enable binary logging.

So I reenabled `log-bin=mysql-bin` in my `/etc/my.cnf`, restarted, PURGED the files (with success now), commented the line again and then restarted. After this the files were removed and no longer created.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this is what happened to you but in my case MySQL had stopped "cycling" logs and the mysql-bin.index file had become "corrupted" with invalid binlog file entries.

Specifically, the index file had started at mysql-bin.000001 and got to mysql-bin.000220 but then had somehow started again from 001. When I compared this to the files on my server I could see that I had files from 001 to 022.

At first I tried `PURGE LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000022';` but this didn't work.

In the end I stopped MySQL and manually edited the index file until it matched the files I had on my server. When I restarted MySQL it cleaned up the binlog files to respect the `expire_logs_days` setting and started working normally again.

Comment: ... and that's how you get your hands dirty fixing MySQL's log rotation. Although this is a very rare occurrence. I have had to do this. Funny thing is, `PURGE LOGS` only works under the ideal setup: 1) when all binary logs are consecutive, 2) all binary logs are named in the `mysql-bin.index` file, 3) There are no extra logs not mentioned in `mysql-bin.index`. +1 !!!

Answer (score 6):

This works for me: (MySQL server version: 5.6.14)

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW();
```

Removes all binary logs on my system.

Comment: Your answer works as long as the binary logs and the binary log index files are perfect aligned. See the answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74498/877 to see when it does not work. Your answer still gets a +1 !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily delete **ALL** logs with:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW();
```

Or replace func NOW() by any date in quotes:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2018-02-15 00:00:00';
```

Or you can automate this action with `expire_logs_days = 10` in my.cnf. By default **expire_logs_days** is **0** = never delete logs.

([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days))