# How to fix a MySQL server with a full hard drive?

Tags: mysql

Overnight, our MySQL server completely filled the hard drive. Now, I cannot login via phpMyAdmin

```
`Cannot log in to the MySQL server`
```

or via the command line

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

or via `mysqladmin`

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
```

There is one big table I can delete as a temporary fix if I can login to the server, but I can't. How can I login?

Comment: Do you have binary logging enabled ???

Comment: I'm not sure (sorry, not a DBA). I see a bunch of `mysql-bin.*` files. Are those binary logs?

Comment: Yes, those are binary logs. What folder are the binary logs in ?

Comment: How many binary logs are there ? Is the DB Server a Master in some replication topology ?

Comment: `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: How much free space is there ? Please run `df -h /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: It's in Docker, so on the machine it is in `/data/mysql/data/`. Running that command, I get: `/dev/sdb1       1.7T  1.6T   69G  96% /data`. I just deleted one of the biggest tables (which we can rebuild via scripts) by deleting the `.frm` and `.idb` files in `/data/mysql/data/<database name>`, hence the new space. But why did it overflow overnight? The binary files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25813/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-gwg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not need to erase the large tables. Why ???

Here is the strange thing about mysql. mysqld uses MyISAM temp tables for it internal operation. When mysqld runs out of space, it does not crash. IT FREEZES !!!

The following is  my answer to 2 year old post ["Site Offline" MySQL server failing to start and stop](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39337/site-offline-mysql-server-failing-to-start-and-stop/39367#39367)

## EXCERPT

According to [**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328127)

[image]
Page 408,409 Section 29.2 Bulletpoint 11 says:

> If you run out of disk space while adding rows to a MyISAM table, no
> error occurs. The server suspends the operation until space becomes
> available, and then completes the operation.

In reality, mysqld is not dead. It is waiting for free diskspace to continue whatever it normally does. Even during startup, if mysqld makes a temp table, it is a MyISAM table. No space left on the disk? No problem. MyISAM just patiently waits for you to make free space.

## END OF EXCERPT

All you had to do was manually delete the binary logs. Then, mysqld would start to function normally. Even deleting just 10 logs would have freed 1G and would make mysqld get going again.

You need to do the following:

Login to mysql and run

```
mysql> RESET MASTER;
mysql> SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days = 7;
```

Then, add this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
expire-logs-days = 7
```

Now, mysqld will automatically delete any binary log older than 7 days.

Comment: Hm, `RESET_MASTER` is not working: `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)` and all the binary files still exist. When I try other commands (looking at this SO http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47048/70573), I get the error, `Target log not found in binlog index`. What's the safest way to clean up those binary files?

Comment: This simply means that the mysql-bin.index file is out of sync with the actual files in `/var/lib/mysql`. You should run `rm -f mysql-bin.0*`. Then, try `RESET MASTER;` again.

Comment: If that does not work, then run `cd /var/lib/mysql ; service mnysql stop ; rm -f mysql-bin.* ; service mysql start`. This will regenerate a new `mysql-bin.index` and create `mysql-bin.000001`